# Memory released from List<> only after new items added

Tags: c#, list, garbage-collection

I'm having an issue freeing memory from a `List<>` when items are removed. It's the strangest thing, memory is only released from the application when a *second set of items* are added and removed from the `List<>`. I was able to illustrate the issue using this simple console application:

`C# .Net4.0`

```
namespace MemoryTestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static int numObjects = 1000;
        static int objectSize = 10000;

        class Obj
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[objectSize];
            public Obj()
            {
                buffer[0] = 1;
                buffer[buffer.Length - 1] = 1;
            }
        }

        private static List<Obj> list = new List<Obj>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while(true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to add {0} objects to list...", numObjects);
                Console.ReadLine();

                //add to list of objects
                for (int i = 0; i < numObjects; i++)
                {
                    list.Add(new Obj());
                }

                //double num objects for next round so we can see which block of memory is released
                numObjects = numObjects * 2;

                Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to remove objects from list...");
                Console.ReadLine();

                foreach (Obj _obj in list.ToList())
                {
                    list.Remove(_obj);
                }

                GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

                Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to trim excess from list...");
                Console.ReadLine();

                list.TrimExcess();

                GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, the block of memory used by items added in round `N` is only released after new items are added then removed in round `N+1` (approximately, this is more easily visible in rounds > 3). I tested the issue using the resolution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17579427/4267590) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17131389/4267590) however the behavior didn't appear to change at all.

This is probably still related to GC behavior but even given the references above I can't make it work as I expect it should. So where is the fault in my code, or my expectations? I greatly appreciate any assistance.

Comment: "memory is only released from the application"... ? Could you please clarify how you measure memory usage and what you see/expect from that application?

Comment: I'm simply watching the private memory usage in the resource monitor, however I have profiled the test app and each `N` round of object memory continues to be identified as `reachable instances` until after the round `N+1` objects are added and removed.  I was expecting the round `N` instances to be unreachable, and the round `N` memory to be released, as soon as the objects in round `N` are removed and the list is trimmed.